# Finite Domain Solver fd_minimize/2

Tags: java, prolog, clpfd, gnu-prolog

I need to minimize a predicate in Prolog. Currently I am using GNU Prolog Java.
I have got this fact

```
army( Territory,X ).
```

It says that the given Territory has got X army. Now I want to find the minimum number of armies owned by a given player. So I am writing:

```
place_army( Player, Territory ):-
    fd_maximize( army(Territory, X), X ),
    owner( Player, Territory ).
```

The interpreter says:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The goal is not currently active

after a bit I have found the problem: http://www.gprolog.org/manual/gprolog.html#htoc313
I assume that the problem is that the Java implementation of the interpreter has got no FD solver. Any hint/workaround?

Answer (score 3):

There are two different systems with a very similar name:

GNU Prolog (see [gnu-prolog](/questions/tagged/gnu-prolog)), an ISO Prolog system with a pioneering CLP(FD) implementation which adopted this name [1999-04-19](https://groups.google.com/group/comp.lang.prolog/browse_thread/thread/34efd5ac8304aeb2/f7b92b6f6bd7d94c) and which is [actively developed](http://gprolog.univ-paris1.fr/unstable/?C=M;O=D) – the most recent version was released an hour ago. `fd_minimize/2` and such are part of GNU Prolog.

And then there is a recent system called [GNU Prolog for Java](http://www.gnu.org/software/gnuprologjava/) - whose most recent version is from [2010-08-15](http://alpha.gnu.org/gnu/gnuprologjava/).

Maybe this naming confusion can be resolved.

Comment: But to make this work with java i have to make a JNI interface!

Answer (score 2):

You could achieve the same result that `fd_minimize/2` provides with `findall/3` and `keysort/2` predicates.

```
 findall(X-T,army(T,X),B),keysort(B,[MinX-Territory|Cs]),
```

could replace

```
  fd_minimize(army(Territory,X),X),
```

providing the same value for `Territory`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The gnu prolog java implementation doesn't provide the Keysort method and I'm a noob in Prolog, so i have wrote this code:
`place_army(Player,Territory):-
    findall( X, army(_,X), Values ),
    sort(Values, [Army | _]),
    army(Territory,Army),
    owner(Player,Territory),!.`

Comment: @Otacon: A cut should be placed immediately after army/2 to maintain equivalence to the other two attempts. Not bad for a noob, anyway!

Comment: Thx a lot for your hints :D (and thanks a lot for the "not bad for a noob") :D
I have decided to switch to SWI-PROLOG. It is a bit heavier but it has got everything I need for my little development :D
However, still, thanks a lot for your support!!!